# Security risk of enabling MSDTC

Tags: c#, distributed-transactions, msdtc

MSDTC is disabled by default (windows 2003 - onwards) and I want to have it enabled for an application I'm developing that requires distributed transactions from .Net C#.

I don't believe there are any security issues with enabling it, but does SO know of any security issues with enabling the DTC?

Cheers

Ollie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the machine is fully patched you should be reasonably safe. AFAIK there may have been some patches in the past for vulnerabilities related to this (but then there is for all components in the OS).

If it is listening on an external port then you may want to lock down the hosts which can connect to it. This would give you a level of protection if some sort of worm on compromise is discovered the in future. It is generally not the sort of thing you want to expose on internet-facing machines.

Comment: how about on machines in the DMZ that are not the front facing web servers - more likely to be app & database servers...

Comment: Those are the places where you typically see MSDTC being used. It really depends on what you are doing, security requirements, budget etc. Some people go as far as putting firewalls between the web and app tiers but that's likely overkill for the majority of people. You could use something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Access_Protection to only allow machines that need MSDTC to talk to one another.